# AdalError in python with API

Tags: python, powerbi, adal

I am trying to use power bi API as shown below
and get this error:

```
import adal
import requests
import json
import pandas
import requests

print(requests.get("https://login.windows.net/common/UserRealm/johndoe@contoso.com?api-version=1.0").text)
```

the output:

```
{"ver":"1.0","account_type":"Managed","domain_name":"contoso.com","cloud_instance_name":"microsoftonline.com","cloud_audience_urn":"urn:federation:MicrosoftOnline"}
```

the inputs:

```
authority_url = 'https://login.windows.net/common'
resource_url = 'https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api'
client_id = 'myclient_id '
username = 'myusername'
password = 'mypassword'

context = adal.AuthenticationContext(authority=authority_url,
                                     validate_authority=True,
                                     api_version=None)
token = context.acquire_token_with_username_password(resource=resource_url,
                                                     client_id=client_id,
                                                     username=username,
                                                     password=password)
```

the error:

```
AdalError: Get Token request returned http error: 400 and server response: {"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"AADSTS90002: Tenant 'domen name' not found. This may happen if there are no active subscriptions for the tenant. Check to make sure you have the correct tenant ID. Check with your subscription administrator.\r\nTrace ID: num-num-num-num-num\r\nCorrelation ID: num-num-num-num-num\r\nTimestamp: 2020-10-18 17:02:34Z","error_codes":[90002],"timestamp":"2020-10-18 17:02:34Z","trace_id":"num-num-num-num-num","correlation_id":"num-num-num-num-num","error_uri":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=90002"}
```

notice: I did some edit on the error message (URL) for privacy reason

any ideas what does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

problem is from the settings

```
authority_url = 'https://login.windows.net/common'
resource_url = 'https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api'
client_id = 'myclient_id '
username = 'myusername'
password = 'mypassword'
```

I don't know wich one, probably client_id

Comment: could please be more specific, what about client_id? @Valentin Garreau